# User logs out on Facebook, JS SDK stops working

Tags: php, sdk, facebook

I know there are similar questions to this around but none seem to quite address the issue I'm having or are referring to the older non-OAuth versions of the SDKs.

I am using both the JS and PHP SDK's as provided by Facebook. Authentication is done using JS with that then setting a cookie that allows the PHP SDK to authenticate, as recommended by Facebook.

This works fairly well until a user logs out of Facebook on their site (i.e. they do not use the FB.logout method on my site). None of the auth.statusChange, auth.authResponseChange or auth.logout methodes are fired either immediately or on the next pageload. However, I can see that cookies are being changed even as I click around the Facebook site (but not the fbsr_xxxxxxxxxx one for the signed request).

My difficulty is that, come the next page load, I have no idea that the user logged out of Facebook. Because I still have the 'fbsr_xxxxxxxxxx' cookie with an access token, I can continue to make API calls through the PHP SDK but the JS SDK becomes totally unresponsive. Methods either complain about not having an access token or fail to run their callback functions entirely.

Am I missing something totally obvious here? I am utterly perplexed so any help really would be most welcome.

FuzzyDunlop

Comment: I'm having the same problem since the move to Oath. Have you made any progress with this issue yet?

Comment: I'm afraid not really. I think I may have to fire the FB.Cookie.clearSignedrequestCookie() method manually. Also, yes, I did not have this problem before using the OAuth version either.

Comment: It sounds to me that you may have had a problem with yout auth.authResponseChange code. Are you able to post what you tried to use? it fires immediately for me

Comment: Something really very simple like this: 

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
 alert('auth reponse change');
 window.location.reload();
});

To be clear, you get en event firing when the users logs out of Facebook separately from interacting with your site? Presumably not straight away but on the next page load? I don't get this. The cookie remains but the JS SDK stops working.

Comment: my problem was specific to logging out. When a user logged out of FB first, then the logout js was failing with an invalid token error.I've fixed my issue by changing from something like this:

`<a href="javascript:fb_logout();">Log Out</a>`

(js)
`var fb_logout = function(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {
 document.location = "http://mysite.url/logout";
    };
};`

to something like this:

`<a href="http://mysite.url/logout" onclick="fb_logout();">Log Out</a>`

(js)
`var fb_logout = function(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {
    });
};`

Now it is not dependent on the response from FB

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a non expiring token, which you can get using the offline access permission, so that you can acces user details from your application even when user logs out of facebook, and that too works until the user doesnt changes his password, if he do so, you again have to
request for a new token.

Comment: Having a non-expiring token allows me to carry on using the PHP API, which wasn't really my issue. The problem I have is that the JS SDK  stops working (even with a non-expiring token) when the user logs out of Facebook but I receive no notification of this.

Comment: Im not sure you really need offline access to fix this issue. there are better ways and this to me would seem a bit overkill and offline access basically suggests your users you want to farm their data while they are sleeping...

Comment: Indeed. I possibly need offline access anyway but I'll try to test without it to see if it is causing the difficulties.

Comment: use any sdk,but if u wnt have offline access n d user logs out of facebook.,,the user will get logged out of ur application tooo

Comment: @user995275 That sounds like exactly what offline access is not. With the exception of the JS SDK, offline access allows you to continue to access their data, when they are, well, offline.